# What is the logic behind these destructor calls

Tags: c++, c++11

I ran the following code

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Count
{
    private:

        int count;      

    public:

        //Constructor
        Count():count(0) { cout << "Constructor called" << endl; }

        //Destructor
        ~Count() { cout << "Destructor called" << endl; }

        //Display the value.
         Count display() 
         { 
               cout << "The value of count is " << count << endl; 
               return *this;
         }

};

int main()
{
    Count C;
    C.display();
}
```

Result :-

```
Constructor called
The value of count is 0
Destructor called
Destructor called
```

In the above case, the destructor is called twice, one for destruction of the "this" object and one for return from main.

Is my observation correct ??

Can anyone explain me also the temporary object created in this process like why it is created, if created??

Comment: Did any of answers help you?

Answer (score 3):

You are returning a copy from `display()` method thus it needs to be destructed too. So, in your main you actually have 2 objects, one - implicitly.

Answer (score 1):

The destructor is called twice because your `display` function returns a copy of the `Count` instance that it is called on. So that gets destroyed along with your `C` instance within `main`.

2 instances = 2 destructor calls.

If you specify and implement your function to return an instance of `Count` then it will do so. If you don't want this behaviour, then change the return type to void and don't return anything - then your code will contain just the one instance `C`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code here

```
    Count display()  { 
 // ^^^^^
             cout << "The value of count is " << count << endl; 
             return *this; // <<<<<<
    }
```

creates an implicit copy of your instance that is returned and immediately destroyed, hence the second destructor call.

Answer (score 0):

Yes correct.

Your function `display()` created a copy which made a second object.

if you return a `reference` you wouldn't get the copy.

```
Count& display() { return *this; }
```

Comment: Just a clarification, the copy happens from "this pointer" to Count, right. And during that copy, do we call default copy constructor ??

Comment: @Sathish Yes, if you create the copy constructor with std::cout you should see it being created.